# Errors in form with ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm not good in English

I want to have a login page, I use ModelForm and LoginView.

when I want to see the page I got this error:

`BaseModelForm.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'`

and when I don't use the Form, always return to the same page. I checked the request.method, it's GET!

here is my form:

```py
class LoginForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

view:

```py
class Login(LoginView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'account/login.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('account:home')
```

and login.html

```html
            <form action="{% url 'account:home' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
            </form>
```

when I use my form(with function view), my browser don't suggest my saved logins.

Answer (score 0):

The `LoginView` is a bit tricky: it passes the request to the form to let the `ModelForm` log in the user, that needs to be removed from the `kwargs` in the super call, like:

```
class LoginForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, request=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

currently, your `LoginForm` will of course not log in the user, and therefore not do much.

---

> **Note**: Since [**PEP-3135** <sup>[pep]</sup>](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/), you don't need to call `super(…)` with parameters if the first parameter is the class in which you define the method, and the second is the first parameter (usually `self`) of the function.

Comment: I don't see the error but it return me to login page again

Comment: @mohammadjavad: that's because as said in the answer, your modelform should authetnicate when validating, and then log in the user with the request. Currently your `ModelForm` does not do anything of that. I however don't really see why you want to make a custom `LoginForm` in the first place?

Comment: @mohammadjavad: typically you subclass `AuthenticationForm`, and let that handle all the work. In this case you don't even change much.

Comment: without `form_class` I redirect to same page again.

I use Form because when I use `{{ form.username }}` in template, I can't set placeholder, but now I don't need it in this way.

Comment: @mohammadjavad: you can just subclass, like `class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm)`, then pass the request to the `super()` as well, and alter it accordingly.